# Scala: *.map(*) running in a Future, how to abort map?

Tags: scala, loops, mapping, future, break

```
@volatile var breakRequested: Boolean = false
// ...
def futureFunc(): Option[Iterable[String]] = {
  val result = hugeList.map { item =>
    if(breakRequested) {
      // put exit code here
      // return None
      // throw AnException
      // what else?
    }
    item.toText() // time-expensive function
  }
  Some(result)
}
Future { futureFunc() }
```

**Given somebody set the `breakRequested` flag to `true`: How may I exit the `map`?**

What I tried:

`return None` => such a `return` transformed into a `scala.runtime.NonLocalReturnControl`: I tried to catch this error, but it seems to be uncatchable (bypasses `try`/`catch`).

`object Cancelled extends Exception`: I tried to throw this but was not able to catch it as well.

All exceptions show up in the command line, when I run the app through SBT.

**If somehow possible, I prefer a solution without `try`/`catch`.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the fast solution, you can convert your **hugeList** to the `Iterator`, and then use `takeWhile`:

```
...
val result = hugeList.toIterator
  .takeWhile(_ => !breakRequested)
  .map { item => 
    item.text
  }
...
```

**Edit:**
Scala's `Future` has no cancellation, but twitter's [Future](https://twitter.github.io/util/docs/#com.twitter.util.Future) has. To cancel this use method `raise`.

Also you can write your own `map`, for example:

```
@annotation.tailrec def map[T,R](
  src: List[T], 
  cancel: => Boolean, 
  dsc: List[R] = List.empty[R])(f: T => R):List[R] = src match {
    case _ if cancel => dsc
    case h :: t => map(t, cancel, f(h) :: dsc)(f)
    case Nil => dsc
}
Future{map(hugeList, breakRequested)(_.text)}
```

If you don't need the result, you can create another future,which will be completed after your `breakRequested` was changed. And use method `Future.firstCompletedOf`.

Comment: This won't work because `takeWhile` exits before `map` gets called. After `takeWhile` is done, break is not possible any more. (The hard mapping work is expected to run in the body of `map`.)

(just coded and ran it though because I was not sure any more)

Comment: Well, I played around for half an hour now and I got it working. Sorry for my over-hasty comment. What made me think it was not working: I did not convert-back the resulting Iterator to a List, which made my `futureFunc` finish earlier than expected and thus the program not act as intended.

Comment: I like both of your solutions a lot. I wish I could give you more than one upvote. Many thanks for your answer!